# How to do Java inheritance/implementing repeating private/protected fields?

Tags: java, repeat, private, lombok, extends

I am trying to implement a java class for all entities of database.
Every entity - class with private fields where all of them contains "created_at" and "updated_at" private fields.

My point of search is to avoid annoying repeating copy-pasted fields for all entities. I suppose this is abstract constructions.

It will be implemented in DAO classes as implementation of every Entity class.

I tried with interfaces and classes but this shouldn't work as multiple inheritance and private implementation from interfaces.

How to do in clear JDBC/Lombok/Java 17 something like this:

--- Option one ---

```
public class Bank implements CreatedAt, UpdatedAt {
    private String name;
    // private LocalDate created_at; - already comes from 'CreatedAt'
    // private LocalDate updated_at; - already comes from 'UpdatedAt'
}
```

--- Option two ---

```
@CreatedAt
@UpdatedAt
// or '@extendFields(CreatedAt, UpdatedAt)'
public class Bank implements CreatedAt, UpdatedAt {
    private String name;
    // private LocalDate created_at; - already comes from '@CreatedAt'
    // private LocalDate updated_at; - already comes from '@UpdatedAt'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to implement [mixins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) but Java doesn't support that concept. Another approach would be with multiple inheritance which Java also doesn't support.

You can have an interface which declares the abstract method and implement them in the concrete classes.

Alternatively you could have base abstract class that implements the methods and inherit it from any class that requires both `CreatedAt` and `UpdatedAt`.

Java supports a basic type of mixin with default methods on interfaces, but there's no support for default attributes.